# Merge and mutate different lists

Tags: r, list, dplyr, merge

I have a list of lists like **out_first** and **out_second**. In each list I have a dataframe (with the same structure, i.e. same dimensions and variable names (id/period/pred_first for **out_first** and id/period/pred_second for **out_second**).

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
period <- c(01,09,12,01,08, 02,08,12,11,12)
pred_first <- c(0.5,0.1,0.15,0.23,0.75,0.6,0.49,0.81,0.37,0.14)

list_1 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_first)

pred_first <- c(0.45,0.18,0.35,0.63,0.25,0.63,0.29,0.11,0.17,0.24)

list_2 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_first)

pred_first <- c(0.58,0.13,0.55,0.13,0.76,0.3,0.29,0.81,0.27,0.04)

list_3 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_first)

pred_first <- c(0.3,0.61,0.18,0.29,0.85,0.76,0.56,0.91,0.48,0.91)

list_4 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_first)

out_first <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)


pred_second <- c(0.4,0.2,0.25,0.33,0.85,0.7,0.59,0.91,0.47,0.24)
list_1 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_second)

pred_second <- c(0.25,0.38,0.75,0.53,0.15,0.83,0.39,0.21,0.37,0.44)

list_2 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_second)

pred_second <- c(0.28,0.03,0.45,0.23,0.16,0.2,0.79,0.91,0.27,0.84)

list_3 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_second)

pred_second <- c(0.4,0.71,0.28,0.39,0.95,0.86,0.66,0.81,0.58,0.81)

list_4 <- data.frame(id, period, pred_second)

out_second <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4)
```

I want to:

1. Merge (list by list) out_first[[i]] with out_second[[i]] (for all lists i) by (id, period) in a new generated list of lists called **out**
2. Make (row by row) differences between pred_first and pred_out (in the new list of lists **out**)

For this example I would do something like the following (in a dataframe environment using dplyr):

```
out <- merge(out_first, out_second, by = c(id, period), all.x=T)
out <- out %>% mutate(pred_dif = pred_first - pred_out)
```

Any idea on how to solve this in an iterative and fast way for all lists?

PS:  Sorry for not sharing real data.

Comment: your sample lists contain only `NULL` ??

Comment: you may use `purrr::map` to join elements of list.  Further use `reduce`.  But I may only demonstrate if you can include 2-3 sample lists?

Comment: No, they have a dataframe. For this example I talk about a dataframe with the following 3 variables (id, period, **pred_first**) for the "out_first" list, and other dataframe with the following 3 variables (id, period, **pred_second**) for the "out_second" list.

Comment: Yes they must have some data.  But the ones you have shared here are just empty!! see this `out_first <- replicate(4, rep(list(NULL), 2), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks Anil! Now you may find an example of data above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `map2`?

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(out_first, out_second, ~ left_join(.x, .y, by = c("id" , "period")) %>%
                                mutate(pred_dif = pred_first - pred_second))
```

Comment: For any reason the code doesn't work (new simulated data in the exercise above)

Comment: I changed it to a `dplyr::left_join`

Comment: How would you merge the list with an external dataframe with the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Map` -

```
Map(function(x, y) {
    transform(merge(x, y, by = c('id', 'period'), all.x=T), 
              pred_dif = pred_first - pred_second)
}, out_first, out_second)
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! Is it possible a closing bracket is missing?

Comment: For any reason the code doesn't work (new simulated data in the exercise above)